# Find all executable files that depend on the specified library in the specified directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, openbsd

My goal is to write a shell script that uses "objdump -p" command to find all executable files that depend on the specified library in the specified directory. (OpenBSD).
I try something like this:

```
find $1 -perm -111 -print0 | xargs -r0 objdump -p | grep -l "NEEDED      $2"
```

But this solution doesn't work because grep cannot figure out the filenames in which it found the given match. The difficulty is to determine the names of the executable files in which grep found the specified library.
Can anyone suggest a solution using the "objdump -p" command?

Comment: So you get no output at all? Do you get a file if you replace `| grep ...` with `> /tmp/myObjects`? Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to execute a shell script rather than a single command to be able to re-use the file name.

```sh
finddepend() {
# Arg 1: The directory where to find
# Arg 2: The library name
  basedir=$1
  libname=$2
  find "$basedir" \
    \( -perm -100 -o -perm -010 -o -perm -001 \) \
    \( -type f -o -type l \) \
    -exec sh -c '
# Arg 0: Is a dummy _ for this inline script
# Arg 1: The executable file path
# Arg 2: The library name
filepath=$1
libname=$2
objdump -p "$filepath" 2>/dev/null |
  if grep -qF "  NEEDED               $libname"; then
    printf %s\\n "${filepath##*/}"
  fi
' _ {} "$libname" \;
}
```

Example usage:

```sh
finddepend /bin libselinux.so
mv
systemctl
tar
sed
udevadm
ls
mknod
systemd
mkdir
ss
dir
vdir
cp
systemd-hwdb
netstat
```

Comment: As I understand this script, it first finds all executable files in the specified directory, and then applies the command (once per path) sh -c to each found path. In turn, the sh-c command runs a shell script from the string ' objdump -p "$0" 2>/dev/null | grep -qF "NEEDED      $1" && echo "${0##*/}" '. But can you please explain 1. where do $0 and $1 come from? 2. And why do we need "$ 2" after {}?

Comment: Also, I made a mistake: Need to change: -perm -111 to \ (-perm -100 -o -perm -010 -o -perm -001 \) to find all executable files

Comment: @Michael GNU `find` has `-executable` *This takes into account access control lists and other permissions artefacts which the `-perm`  test  ignores.*

Comment: But in OpenBSD the find command has no such option. Can you please answer the first comment?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use `objdump` when you can use `ldd` (List Dynamic Dependencies)? `objdump` gives a complete summary, which you need to process in order only to get the information you're looking for, while `ldd` only gives you that information.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you, but my task requires me to use objdump - p